# How to use Naive Bayes Binary Classification in CoreML?

Tags: ios, coreml

I am trying to build a number classification model in CoreML and want to use the naive bayes classifier but not able to find how to use it. My algorithm is using naive bayes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment, coremltools support only following types of classifiers:

- SVMs (scikitlearn)
- Neural networks (Keras, Caffe)
- Decision trees and their ensembles (scikitlearn, xgboost)
- Linear and logistic regression (scikitlearn)

However, implementing Naïve Bayes in Swift yourself is not that hard, check this [implementation, for example](https://github.com/ayanonagon/Parsimmon/blob/master/Parsimmon/NaiveBayesClassifier.swift).